# Excel VBA Identifying duplicates with a condtion

Tags: excel, if-statement, match, vba

Quite new to this, so still trying to get my footing.

I'm Looking for a rule, where any duplicates within a column is identified, and then, if it is, whether in another column, those two duplicates sum to zero.

For example:

[image: Example]

In the basic image example, the first two rows will be identified as a match whereas the last two will not, because they don't sum to zero.

I've used the following code that will highlight a single column, however, I'm not sure how to encorporate an additional rule where the sum of two duplicates is 0:

```
Sub Duplicate_Shade()
`Dim cel As Variant
 Dim myrng As Range
 Set myrng = Range("A2:A" & Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row)
 myrng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
 For Each cel In myrng
 clr = 10
 If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrng, cel) > 1 Then
 cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 26
 clr = clr + 10
 End If
 Next
 End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Red, I'm afraid this site is not a "write code for me for free" service. You'll have to make a start on your own. When you get stuck, ask a question.

Comment: Teylyn, I've actually tried to make an attempt. Besides, I have actually attempted, its just I'm new to this. And also I am not requesting a "Service" .

Comment: Use Pivot Table. No need VBA

Comment: Privyet Anastasiya-Romanova, Pivots are a great way to do this, so is conditional formatting (whereby the duplicates are shaded), I'm trying to figure out an automated way

Comment: ok, so here's the hint. To do this in VBA, check out `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly minimal change to your code would be:

```
Sub Duplicate_Shade()
    Dim myrng As Range
    Set myrng = Range("A2:A" & Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row)
    myrng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    For Each cel In myrng
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrng, cel) > 1 And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(myrng, cel, myrng.Offset(, 1)) = 0 Then
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 26
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```